# How is it possible that Google and Youtube, outlook.com and msn.com use same account?

Tags: http, authentication, kerberos, ntlm

How do browsers share credentials belonging to one domain with other? As I asked in question, if I log into one service, I'm automatically logged into other service? What authentication scheme is this and how are credentials shared?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that they use OAuth or something like it. You can read about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth or just google for OAuth. Only one site receives your username and password. The others are granted permissions by that site.

Comment: I suppose they want to know how you keep authenticated even without going through a log-in process on the website. E.g.: You are logged out all websites. You log on Youtube. When you visit Gmail, you are authenticated as well without going through the login process on Gmail.

Answer (score -1):

By using API's.
For example: When you going to Youtube and you want to log in, then Youtube uses Googles API's to check if there is an account that equals with your details.
And in case of logging in automatically, just the same way, but then with a session or cookie I think.

Comment: It is not a session because you keep logged in even if you close your browser. They actually use cookies to store your information.

Comment: Yes indeed you're right, but it sounds kind of scary that your details are stored in a file which is accessible by other websites..

Comment: As noted by Chris Lear, cookies can be read only on the same domain. So Google's cookies cannot be read by Facebook, for example. 

However, if someone gets access to your computer, your cookies can be retrieved and read. 

That's why it is important to encrypt the contents of cookies.

Comment: What's more, the cookie doesn't contain your username or password. It contains only a session token, which has an expiry date (normally 2 hours). So even if someone steals your cookie, they normally can't simply take over your account for ever. This is a complicated subject, but if you're prepared to take the time to read it, the OAuth documentation will help.

Answer (score -2):

They use cookies to save your (encrypted) information.

<s>Cookies stored on your browser are readable by any website</s>*, so in theory any website that knows how Google's authentication scheme works is able to "log you in" on a Google account.

Also, in theory, any person who "steals" your cookies and use it on their computer would be able to log in as you. However there are certainly security measures taken into consideration from Google before allowing you to authenticate using only a cookie (using IP and other request information to make sure that cookie belongs to you, etc)

As a proof of concept, if you delete all cookies on your browser created by google.com you will find out that you are logged out of Google's websites. And when you log back in, the cookies will be recreated.

Errata:
*Cookies can be read by websites under the same domain.

Comment: "Cookies stored on your browser are readable by any website". This claim is simply false. The rest of this answer is misleading.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant domain. They are all under Google's domain, so they can read their cookies.